# Drop down list with links excel

Tags: excel, list, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

There are several cells with links to files on local disk (images for instance) that I would like to group in a single drop-down list (or menu). So that this list has rather buttons, than selectable options. The aim is to free cells and leave those links only on the list.
As it's shown on the picture, all 3 links should be grouped in a single drop-down list. The question is how to assign URLs to the names on the list so that when I click on them a file opens rather then options's value is copied to cell's value. I can tab links' names (because mostly they'll be same everywhere) somewhere on the workbook to make a list of, but URLs shouldn't appear anywhere else.
I have found a couple of ways of creating a drop down list, but I can't assign anything to the objects on the list.
I tried making links for the whole sell while one of list items is chosen, but it links all options too.

Also I would like the initial text of the cell to stay when I click on one of the list items.
Is it possible?

[Transformation example (photoshop applied)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSBtF.png)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar Rewrote question and it should represent my problem pretty much fully. And my question doesn't imply any code.

Comment: @MrCheatak what do the links look like? Are you trying to create a 'clickable' hyperlink to a website or filepath?

Comment: @girlvsdata exactly, its a 'clickable' link to an external file (image for instance)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an option of how you could do it:**

[image: links screenshot]

In cell C2 there is a data validation dropdown that points to A1:A3

In cell D2 is the following formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(C2,"Click Here")
```

The link on D2 will change depending on the selection in C2.

---

***Edit:*** *Another option based on new information that OP's links are not raw URLs*

**Since your URLs are not accessible in your links, here's another option:**

[**This user**](http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/) has created a User Defined function that can work around the problem, and it is very easy to use.

> **To install this all you need to do is:**
>
> 1. Hit ALT + F11 (Opens Visual Basic Editor)
> 2. Click on Insert -> Module (adds a module to your excel file)
> 3. Paste the code below for the function of GETURL
> 4. Hit ALT + Q (Closes the Visual Basic Editor)
>
> **GETURL Function:**
>
> ```
> Function GETURL(HyperlinkCell As Range)
>
>   GETURL = HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
>
> End Function
> ```

[image: geturl]

Code in **B2**:

```
=GETURL(A2)
```

**E1** contains dropdown box pointing to A1:A4

Code in **E2**:

```
=HYPERLINK(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),D2)
```

Comment: the thing is there will be a lot of links to external files (maybe 50 or more) and with this it comes to listing all file paths somewhere on the sheet.

Comment: @MrCheatak Can you please update your question to include a sample of what your workbook might look like, how the links are structured and an example of what you want the end product to look like? It will remove a lot of the guesswork so we can provide a better answer for you.

Comment: @grlvsdata Thanks for digging in. Added an example of how it all should look like. Its pretty simple though. This template will just be used all over the workbook in the same way with only changing number of linked cells in a group.

Comment: @MrCheatak I see, you already have the text hyperlinked, you don't have the address separate. You could try my above example but also make use of this user's 'User Defined Function' called "=GETURL" here: http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/ which would just add an extra step, transform the link to URL first with "=GETURL()" and then readd the link with "=HYPERLINK()"

Comment: @MrCheatak I've edited my answer with information about GETURL

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't unclear, but the aim is to free cells and "transfer" links  to a compact list. So that they don't waste space on a workbook. Edited picture to show it. Anyway, GETURL method is useful to know. Function in E2 could be modified to "=HYPERLINK(GETURL(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,A:A,0))),D2)" so it doesn't need additional column with links.

Comment: @MrCheatak glad I could help a little at least! If you've figured it out, please add your own answer so that this post can help people in future :)